# How to start X windows inside "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows"

Tags: bash, xorg, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After installing the new feature (still "Beta") called [Bash on Ubuntu on Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) that is a feature subset of Windows 10 Anniversary edition, I get the following message when trying to start X-Windows using `startx` :

[image: x-windows subsystem failure on ubuntu]

What do I need to tweak / configure in order for X-Windows to launch?

I noticed that `xauth` was already installed, however I had to install the rest of the framework as follows :

```
apt-get install xorg openbox
```

Comment: @Zanna thank you for the correction.  I missed that misspelling of `windows` (prior :  `widnows`  lol).

Comment: :) it's nothing! Hope someone can answer :)

Comment: @KraangPrime can you update us on your progress with x-windows on Windows 10 WSL?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix - I haven't tried anything recently. I did notice it is finally available in the Windows Store https://aka.ms/wslstore [ if on windows that link will prompt to open the Store and display the Linux subsystems available ] after running `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux` in PowerShell as Administrator

Answer (score 3):

You can install Xming.

Use `export DISPLAY=:0` or `export DISPLAY=localhost:0` and run your app from the console.

Comment: +1 but there are other x-windows packages that can be used and you can improve your answer with references to them as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get either `Xming-6-9-0-31-setup` or `vcxsrv-64.1.20.8.1.installer` to work with windows 10 Ubuntu bash command line, I tried using commands like `export DISPLAY=:0` or `export DISPLAY=localhost:0` it doesn't seem to send it to either of these apps under Windows 10, I was unable to get them to work I also got the message about unable to connection to X server connection refused type message too, I am now trying to use Debian `bash` command under Windows 10 to see if I have any better luck, the only thing I been able to get X server to run under is Remote Desktop Connection with `localhost:3390`, I found that info but then under Ubuntu I installed `scummvm` app and it can't find the path for `/etc/games` for the app that type of error message when trying to run it, I was able to get the lite shell not gnome to work with that, found a page online on how to do so, otherwise I have no luck making it work without using remote desktop connection that `Xming` app doesn't seem to work for me. Unless I did something wrong when trying to run it which I don't think I did.

https://autoize.com/xfce4-desktop-environment-and-x-server-for-ubuntu-on-wsl-2/

This page on getting `xfce4` working may help again its not gnome shell or `kde` shell I would prefer getting those to work over `xfce4`. I hope that helps.

not sure what I am doing wrong I found the `ipconfig` for `WSL` in `cmd` and input it into display but I still can't get it to work right, I tried both `Xming` and `vcxsrv` software.

```
$ startxfce4
/usr/bin/startxfce4: X server already running on display **
xrdb: Can't open display '**'
xfce4-session: Cannot open display: .
Type 'xfce4-session --help' for usage.
```

If you have problems with WSL 2 also this link may help:

1. https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1800
2. https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4106
3. https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/xfce-xserver-already-running-on-display0.64651/

I was able to get X server to only run when using MobaXterm app. otherwise no luck otherwise so far, I think its better supported when using WSL 2 maybe has to do with the network for WSL ip info stuff. had to set X11 to Full in MobaXterm software to run it correctly.

https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/download.html